# How to getting value from array javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
const array = [
  {
    text: "hello",
    number: 23,
  },
];

const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", createText);

function createText() {
  const newText = document.createElement("h1");
  newText.innerText = `${array.text}`;

  container.appendChild(newText);
}
```

i want to get value text from array? what is wrong? why i get undefined ??

Answer (score 1):

Your this code needs to be changed to

```
newText.innerText = `${array[0].text}`;
```

Comment: Hey i haven't why will i do that

Comment: what do you mean bro? I do not understand, sorry I just new joined this site xD ..

Answer (score 0):

```
array[0].text
```

But you should change the structure of "array"... For the moment you have an array with only one element, and it's an object.

Either you want to handle an array of objects, or you want to only have one element, in that case you use an object:

```
const case1 = [
  {
    text: "hello",
    number: 23,
  },
  {
    text: "hello2",
    number: 2345,
  }
];

const case2 = {
  text: "hello",
  number: 23,
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it work ... is the array writing wrong?

Comment: oo i see xD .. thnk you one more time for the insight

Comment: ohh, I understand now, thank you so much, I learned a lot here